# angularjs - how to insert an app inside an iframe

Tags: angularjs, iframe

I search for a long time and find answers that didn't helped me so far, i want to put an angular app inside iframe.

My index.html upload with flask.

How can i put my app inside iframe?

Thanks

Comment: <iframe src="index.html"></iframe> and let index be your angular app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think about `angular` application outside of an `iframe`. Page inside of `iframe` is just like your "parent" page, it must have it's own angularjs script included and own application bootstrapped.

[Live demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/rjhtZMdHwd79iT4PPUyb?p=preview)

Comment: i used Noppey suggestion and the app is working but cant do any $http request, can i configure that my app look into my original project?

Comment: So basically you have `index.html` which instantiates angular application and has an iframe in it that points to the `index.html` (the page it originated from). Inside of an iframe **new separate angular application** is running, which is not aware of the fact it is inside of iframe, and knows nothing about application outside of iframe. If you want a communication between page and iframe you need [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), but honestly I don't think you need to have the same app running in iframe.

Comment: as you said i have index.html that recognize my whole app (.py files etc.) and this file has an iframe that point to indexApp.html that in "static" folder. so now my app see only files that inside "static" folder so http request cant working (work on "views.py" file outside static folder) i cant change the hierarchy of the files (put "views" in static folder) what should id do?

Comment: @talazouri it is not related to original question. You should create a new one, but close this one before (by accepting my answer if it was helpful).